# Applescript to Delete Watched TV Shows from iTunes Library

Tags: applescript, itunes

Here is what I’m trying to do with the actual code:
if (there are multiple episodes in a tvshow folder AND at least one episode is marked as unwatched){
delete the watched episodes
}

My goal here is to always leave a single episode in the TVShow folder. Even if that show is marked as watched or unwatched. The only condition where deletion occurs is when there are multiple episodes and one of those episodes is marked as unwatched. I need this script to run on ALL the tvshows in iTunes. This will keep my iTunes account smaller and auto delete watched shows for me. Anyone know how to do this? I’m very new to Applescripting. 


BTW, and if it matters, the TVShows I'm referring to are ones that I've added to the iTunes library OUTSIDE of the iTunes store. This script will not be deleting purchased tvshows. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing a script which deletes something is always quite dangerous.

As your request is a bit ambiguous

> *… at least one episode is marked as unwatched*
>      and
>   *… a single episode … even if that show is marked as watched or unwatched*

the script is going to delete all watched episodes in the playlist `TV Shows` if there is at least one unwatched episode.
All unwatched episodes are **not** deleted.

**There are two scripts one for testing and and one for deleting.**

---

**Script #1 doesn't delete anything** but displays the list of the items which are supposed to be deleted.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0
    set unwatchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is true
    if (count unwatchedEpisodes) > 0 then
        set trackNames to {}
        repeat with anEpisode in watchedEpisodes
            set end of trackNames to ((name of anEpisode) as text) & " of show " & show of anEpisode
        end repeat

        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}
        display dialog trackNames as text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end if
end tell
```

**Please check the output carefully**

---

**Script #2 deletes the items matching the criteria**

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0
    set unwatchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is true

    if (count unwatchedEpisodes) > 0 then
        repeat with anEpisode in watchedEpisodes
            delete anEpisode
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you @vadian for helping me with this. Using a test script is genius. I appreciate you being that considerate. When using the test script I am getting the following error: "error "iTunes got an error: Can’t get database ID of every track of user playlist id 5271 of source id 64." number -1728 from database ID of every track of user playlist id 5271 of source id 64"

Comment: I tested the script with the current version of iTunes (12.2.1) Has the playlist "TV Shows" a different name? Or it might be that the playlist "Purchased" has a different identifier

Comment: Also, I wanted to clear things up. I'm trying to get to a place that I always have 1 episode of each tv show in my library. Even if that show has been watched. The reason for this is because it helps me track where I'm at within the season. If I look at the iTunes library and see that I have Friends season 3 episode 2 as the most recent episode (even though I watched it), I know to import season 3 episode 3. Once I upload episode 3, I would like the script to delete episode 2. This way, I always have 1 episode in the library, even if it is watched. Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: I am also using iTunes 12.1.1. If it helps you can remove the part of the script that includes purchased TV shows. I don't have any and don't plan on ever getting them. The only reason I mentioned it in the original post was to explain that I was only using imported shows, not purchased ones. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you again @vadian, I really appreciate your help. That last change worked, however it lists shows that I'm in the middle of watching. Can the logic in the code change to only delete shows that are completely watched?

Comment: try `set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0`. If a track is completely played the counter is supposed to be increased.

Comment: That did it!!!! How awesome! This will make things much easier on me, thank you. The only thing I'd still like to see, if possible, is to add the requirement that it won't delete a tvshow if that's the only show left in the tvshow folder. I would like to keep at least one episode for each tv show even if that episode is watched. Is that possible? If not, this will still be beneficial to me. Again, thank you for all your help.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea to do that at the moment

Comment: No worries. As I said, I'm still better off with what you've provided. Much appreciated!

Comment: It failed when running the actual script. Here is the error: error "iTunes got an error: track id (item 1 of {2600, 2466, 2580, 520, 2576, 2620, 2546, 2586, 2536, 2654, 2612, 2594, 2478, 2564, 2566, 2568, 2610, 2604, 2550, 2622, 2552, 2592, 2606, 2712, 2486}) of playlist \"TV Shows\" doesn’t understand the “delete” message." number -1708 from track id (item 1 of {2600, 2466, 2580, 520, 2576, 2620, 2546, 2586, 2536, 2654, 2612, 2594, 2478, 2564, 2566, 2568, 2610, 2604, 2550, 2622, 2552, 2592, 2606, 2712, 2486}) of playlist "TV Shows"

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post again, now it should work

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!